# Google Cloud Firewall: is there an option to filter outside Google traffic

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-networking

From what I understood from [pricing](https://cloud.google.com/network-tiers/pricing), traffic from outside Google Cloud is free, traffic to inside Google Cloud is free, but traffic to outside Google Cloud is not.

So I think the realistic question is is there an option to filter in GC Network Firewall traffic from outside Google Cloud? Tag it, filter it, provide tag to GCE, anything.

One option would be to find out Google Cloud AS numbers and subnets.

EDIT:

I don't understand if I'm unclear, but I do not wish to deny all outgoing traffic. Outgoing traffic from GCE Google is ok.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can create firewall rule for outbounding traffic(egress).

Comment: @xirehat Can i create an outbound rule that outbound traffic from my GCE is allowed except going out of Google ?

Comment: Yes, at first you need create a rule to allow outgoing traffic to GCE network range then create a rule to disallow all. rule's priority is important.

Answer (score 2):

When creating a firewall rule in VPC firewall. There is an option that you can deny all traffic. Under “Direction of Traffic” there is an option “egress”, then on “Action Match” you can choose “Deny”.

From option “Protocol and Ports” you have an option to deny all or just deny the specific ports. For more information and guidance on this feature, you can follow this [link](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules)

You can also check [VPC Firewall Rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#:%7E:text=VPC%20firewall%20rules%20let%20you,they%20have%20not%20started%20up.) for more information about this feature.